# Unit Test VSCode Custom Snippet

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

### Context:

I am following the guide https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_create-your-own-snippets in writing my own custom snippet in vscode.

### Question:

1. is it a good practice to test for the custom snippet that I created? If yes, how can I do that?

I read through this https://code.visualstudio.com/api/working-with-extensions/testing-extension doc but can't really understand the process of testing through custom snippet. Here is the sample code given by the tutorials https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/blob/main/helloworld-test-sample/src/test/suite/extension.test.ts, assume that I am using mocha for the unit test (which is shown in the doc above). How can I write a test for custom code snippet since what I did is just add key value pair to the `snippet.json`?

Comment: what do you mean with `custom snippet`? How do you want to `debug snippet`?

Comment: I added some context to the question, hope that it make more sense now.

Comment: you can load the editor with a predefined content, place the cursor at a certain location, than use a command to execute a snippet. The problem is that you don't have user interaction in the test and I don't know how to mock that, maybe the `type` command can help. Just assume the snippet works if you use it, I assume you have tried the snippet and we can assume the features as described in the doc work.